# Verifying Veracrypt's public key

Tags: digital-signature

I execute the following command, as discussed in several sites:

```
gpg --with-fingerprint VeraCrypt_PGP_public_key.asc
```

Against current key here [VeraCrypt download](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html)

The output I receive is as follows:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-11 [SC]
uid           VeraCrypt Team (2018 - Supersedes Key ID=0x54DDD393) <veracrypt@idrix.fr>
sub   rsa4096 2018-09-11 [E]
sub   rsa4096 2018-09-11 [A]
```

Is this supposed to happen? How does this help me verify the public key as none of the information relates to what is shown in the link for ID/Fingerprint?

Comment: No that is not the output you want (I'm getting the same result). you want to see the fingerprint for the key, and verify that it matches the one posted on the site. you don;t want to import a key into gpg if it is suspect, so verifying the fingerprint tells you whether the key was modified during the download process. after you import the key, you can use GPG to verify the download by using its signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, Take out the `--with-fingerprint` option. it will print the fingerprint on the third line of output.

`gpg VeraCrypt_PGP_public_key.asc`

Note that this is not technically a correct use of gpg, since it doesn't provide a command, but it will work.

See more info here if you really want to learn to do it right:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335669/gnupg-2-1-16-with-fingerprint-no-longer-works-to-show-fingerprints